# How to dispaly the three biggest numbers of one of the columns of a database table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have to write a `php` script to find the three biggest numbers of a column in a database table. This is my code so far, but it doesn't work .

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db=mysql_select_db("pool");

 $res1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM buy ORDER BY value LIMIT 3 ");

 while($r1=mysql_fetch_array($res1)){
     echo $r1['value']; 
  }
?>
```

Comment: `ORDER BY value desc`

Comment: 1. stop using `mysql_*`(deprecated+removed).2 use mysqli_* or PDO 3. `"SELECT column   FROM buy ORDER BY <same column name> DESC LIMIT 3 "`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM `buy` ORDER BY `value` DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: The values in my table are  10  5  6  7  12.  When i add DESC it gives 7  6  5

Comment: the values in your website should be `int` type in database, this happens because you must have it as `varchar` @angie

Comment: @angie meanwhile check my suggestion

Comment: @angie glad this was helpful :)